# How to erase and format a Ubuntu USB from Mac OS Catalina?

Tags: ubuntu, live-usb, macos

I was told that this is the correct forum for this question after posting it on Ask Ubuntu.

I am on Mac OS Catalina however I have other machines that I'd like to turn into Ubuntu machines. The USB I'm using also currently has Ubuntu on it, but it's an older version, so I need to wipe it.

I should mention I have tried this while changing the format to both ExFAT and MS-DOS(FAT).

When I try to mount the old Ubuntu USB to my Mac:

```
Could not mount “disk2s2”. (com.apple.DiskManagement.disenter error -119930868.)
```

According this [this post](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250718774?answerId=251448695022#251448695022) about that error message, this is a Catalina issue.

When I try to erase it WITHOUT mounting it:

```
Erasing "disk2s2" and creating "UNTITLED"
Unmounting Disk
Couldn't modify partition map.:(-69874)
Operation failed...
```

I've tried erasing it through disk utility as well as recovery mode. I have yet to find a method of erasing it through the command line.

Comment: What exactly is your Ubuntu drive? Is it a live/installation ISO or the installed system you run?

Comment: This is a pretty stupid comment, but here goes nothing: have you tried using Balena Etcher to burn your ISO onto the USB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you only want to update your Ubuntu live disk with a new ISO image, then 
   just install the new image to the drive as you did earlier. No need to delete first.
2. If it's about formatting a drive that previously contained an Ubuntu ISO image, then you most likely have to remove the odd partitioning that these ISOs bring.

   Use your partitioning program to write a new partition table (usually MBR) to the USB drive. Then create a new partition and format it.

   **Be careful with the partition manager because it will destroy your data if you chose the wrong drive.**

And about the error message: this is most likely caused by the non-standard partitioning from the ISO image. It's not really the fault of MacOS. A lot of partition managers fail on it. As already told, the best way to get rid of it is to write a new partition table.